# Using spei() function on time series from rasterstack in R?

Tags: raster, r, time-series

I want to use the spei() function in the SPEI package on a raster stack of monthly time series of water balance data. The stack has 30 years of monthly data, so 360 layers. The documentation for spei() https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SPEI/SPEI.pdf states the input should be "a vector, matrix or data frame with time ordered values", along with a lag (number of months). Can I run spei() without converting each pixel in the stack to a time series vector? I have explored this thread -> [Apply SPEI::hargreaves function to time series from each pixel rasterbrick R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240775/apply-speihargreaves-function-to-time-series-from-each-pixel-rasterbrick-r) which got me started setting dates as the Z dimension in the stack.

```
library(raster)
library(SPEI)
library(zoo)

wb.files <- list.files(path = <pathway to files>, full.names = TRUE)
wb.stack <- stack(wb.files)
dates <- seq(as.Date("1971-01-01"), as.Date("2000-12-31"), by="month")
wb.stack <- setZ(wb.stack, dates)
names(wb.stack) <- as.yearmon(getZ(wb.stack))
```

Then when I try to run the function, I get an error.

```
system.time(spei.r <- spei(wb.stack, 2))
```

The error I get is:

```
#Error in sum(is.na(data)) > 0 & na.rm == FALSE : 
#  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

In the thread above, the raster::overlay() function is used, and the equivalent for a single raster stack is calc() so I tried using that too.

```
speicalc <- function(dat, sc) {
  SPEI::spei(dat, sc)
} 

system.time(spei.r <- raster::calc(wb.stack, 2, fun = speicalc))
```

The error I get in that case is:

```
#Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : cannot use this function
```

I would like to avoid collapsing every pixel to a vector or data frame, which seems like it would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `spei()` function is an object of class `spei` with multiple elements and as such, `calc()` does not know what to do with it.

So, guessing that you want to extract the $fitted part of the output of `spei` [i.e., **fitted**: *time series with the values of the Standardized Precipitation-Evapotranspiration Index (SPEI) or the Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI)*] you need to extract only that part (which is a `ts` object) convert it to a numeric vector that `calc` likes and also pass the `scale` parameter in the modified `spei` function. It gets like this:

--- [Edited in 28/03/2018] ---

```r
library(SPEI)
library(raster)

# Generate a sample raster stack time series with 360 layers (this will take a while...)
r <- raster(nrows=10,ncols=10,vals=rnorm(100))
rstack <- stack(r)
for(i in 1:359){
  rstack <- stack(rstack, raster(nrows=10,ncols=10,vals=rnorm(100)))
  cat(paste("..",round(((i+1)/360)*100,1),"%")) # check progress in %
}

# Change the function SPEI so it outputs a numeric vector from fitted
# Pass scale value
rstSPEI <- calc(rstack, fun = function(x, scale = 2, na.rm = TRUE, ...) as.numeric((spei(x, scale = scale, na.rm = na.rm, ...))$fitted))

# Or using your example
spei.r <- raster::calc(wb.stack, fun = function(x, scale = 2, na.rm = TRUE, ...) as.numeric((spei(x, scale = scale, na.rm = na.rm, ...))$fitted))
```

[Note: I am not sure why but, the first image returned by `spei` in the example is `NA`... (explained!: check comments below)]

You can also declare the function outside and use it in `calc` making a specific reference to the `na.rm` parameter (which usually gives some problems) like this:

```
# Declare the function to use
funSPEI <- function(x, scale=2, na.rm=TRUE,...) as.numeric((spei(x, scale=scale, na.rm=na.rm, ...))$fitted)

rstSPEI <- calc(rstack, fun = funSPEI)
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works on the test raster stack (except I removed the second comma after scale = 2). The first layer in the result is NA because the two month lag does not work for the first month in the series, so that makes sense. But when I try this with my data I get the same error as above: Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : cannot use this function.

Comment: Am I getting this error because calc() works on chunks of the data but actually needs to have access to the entire series? If so, how can I do this without calc()? The raster stack I'm trying to use has dimensions 585 x 1386 x 360

Comment: Hi! Actually `calc` works on the entire series in a per pixel basis (from the help you get this: "If x is a RasterStack or RasterBrick, fun should operate on a vector of values (one vector for each cell)"). The problem here is that the function seems not to be working on your case (which is difficult to check what is happening exactly without accessing the data). Try this out:
`funSPEI <- function(x, scale=2, na.rm=TRUE,...) as.numeric((spei(x, scale=scale, na.rm=na.rm, ...))$fitted);
rstSPEI <- calc(rstack, fun = funSPEI)`

Comment: Hi again! I was able to generate your error and it is happening because of `NA`'s in the series so, if you turn the `na.rm=TRUE`, the problem seems to be fixed. Check out the edited solution above.

Comment: I have run into calc() and overlay() failing during the internal check, for no apparent reason, so many times that, if possible, I coerce into my stack into a SpatialPixelsDataFrame object and then use apply() to operate on rows.

Comment: Thank you! @Kamo. Your solution with na.rm=TRUE looks like it worked for my data.

Comment: Kamo or @JeffreyEvans How would I take the coefficients produced by as.numeric((spei(x, scale=scale, na.rm=na.rm, ...))$coefficients which are in the form of a rasterstack with 36 layers and use them as custom parameters in a subsequent spei() call with the param argument specified? spei() expects a 3 x 12 array of param for each pixel (3 coefficients x 12 months). -- if this should be a new thread I can start that. Thank you.

Comment: For clarity, I decided to make this a new question -- here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277950/use-spei-function-with-user-specified-parameters-from-a-rasterstack-in-r

Comment: @jeffrey-evans how would I go about this using a SpatialPixelsDataFrame and then convert back to a raster stack?

Comment: @jk22 you can coerce a raster stack to a SpatialPixelsDataFrame object, then you have a data.frame object in the data slot. You can use apply to pass a function to row or columns (margin) of the data.frame. The results are ordered so, can be related directly back to the object and then coerced back to a raster class object. So, it you have a raster stack where each raster is a parameter value in a model, this would be an efficient solution. This coercion can be accomplished using: as(x, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")

Comment: @jeffrey-evans Great! Thank you! How would I then coerce the resulting matrix back to a raster stack that is comparable to my initial raster stack? That is, how would I convert from a matrix of, say, 100 rows x 360 columns to a raster stack of 360 layers of 10 pixels x 10 pixels like the one I started with?

Comment: @JeffreyEvans I got this to run using as.matrix() on the stack, then setValues() to convert the resulting matrix back to a raster brick. Thanks for your help!