# What does "sc =" part of code mean in answer for Use spei() function with user specified parameters from a rasterstack in R?

Tags: raster, r, standardized-precipitation-index

This is a question in relation to [Use spei() function with user specified parameters from a rasterstack in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277950)

In [@jk22's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/117429/jk22) answer:

```
library(SPEI)
library(raster)
library(zoo)

# Generate a sample raster stack time series with 720 layers
# This would be 60 years of monthly data
r <- raster(nrows=10,ncols=10,vals=rnorm(100))
rstack <- stack(r)
for(i in 1:719){
  rstack <- stack(rstack, raster(nrows=10,ncols=10,vals=rnorm(100)))
  cat(paste("..",round(((i+1)/720)*100,1),"%")) # check progress in %
}

r.mat <- as.matrix(rstack)

# Run spei()
funSPEImat <- function(x, sc, start, end, na.rm=TRUE,...) {
  dat <- ts(x, start = c(1971, 1), end = c(2030, 12), frequency = 12)
  as.numeric((spei(dat, sc, ref.start = start, ref.end = end, na.rm=na.rm, ...))$fitted) 
}

fitted.mat <- t(apply(r.mat, 1, funSPEImat, sc = 2, start = c(1971, 1), 
                                 end = c(2000, 12)))


# Convert back to raster brick
spei <- setValues(rstack, fitted.mat)
dates <- seq(as.Date("1971-01-01"), as.Date("2030-12-31"), by="month")
names(spei) <- as.yearmon(dates)
```

it is my understanding that the section below is the function that generates the Standardised Precipitation Evapotranspiration Index (SPEI):

```
# Run spei()
funSPEImat <- function(x, sc, start, end, na.rm=TRUE,...) {
  dat <- ts(x, start = c(1971, 1), end = c(2030, 12), frequency = 12)
  as.numeric((spei(dat, sc, ref.start = start, ref.end = end, na.rm=na.rm, ...))$fitted) 
}
```

and this next part of the code is to generate the reference period (in this case January 1971 to December 2000):

```
fitted.mat <- t(apply(r.mat, 1, funSPEImat, sc = 2, start = c(1971, 1), 
                                 end = c(2000, 12)))
```

What does the `sc = 2` part relate to in the reference period code above?

I cannot find any reference to `sc =` in the  documentation ([Package ‘SPEI’](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SPEI/SPEI.pdf)). I guess this is for the scale - but there is already a "1" scale reference following "r.mat" in the above code which I think would make this a 1 monthly spei.

"sc" does feature in the function that generates the SPEI but would this mean that there is a 2 monthly spei generated which uses a 1 monthly reference period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help for this function starts its description like this:

```
spei(data, scale, kernel = list(type ='rectangular', shift = 0),....
```

In R, arguments get matched by position and by name **if called with a `name=value` argument**.

The name of the thing holding the value (`sc` in this case) is irrelevant. The following are equivalent:

```
sc = 99
z = 99
# match by position
spei(mydata, sc, .....)
# match by name, but in the same positions:
spei(data=mydata, scale=sc, .....)
# match by name, different positions:
spei(scale=z, data=mydata, .....)
# doesn't matter what the name of the thing with the value is:
spei(mydata, z, ......)
spei(mydata, scale=z,.....)
spei(mydata, ....., scale=z)
spei(scale=z, data=mydata, ......)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments and answer received It made me realise that my *Further Comments* assumptions within my question are wrong. The "*which I think would make this a 1 monthly spei*" part is incorrect. The 1 after r.mat below actually relates to the [apply function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/apply);

```
fitted.mat <- t(apply(r.mat, 1, funSPEImat, sc = 2, start = c(1971, 1), 
                                     end = c(2000, 12)))
```

Where;

```
apply(X, MARGIN, FUN, …)
```

MARGIN relates to "*a vector giving the subscripts which the function will be applied over. E.g., for a matrix 1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns, c(1, 2) indicates rows and columns*" (see [apply function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/apply)).

So, in the example within the question the 1 in the "fitted.mat" is linked to the apply function not the spei function i.e. applies the function to a matrix.